# Continuous RVs have 0 probability for any specific value, measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

Define a probability space: $(\Omega, F, P)$.

It is my understanding that for any continuous RV X, $Pr(X=x) = 0$ because $Pr(X \in A)$ for any set A is calculated as such:

$Pr(X \in A) = PX^{-1}(A) = \int_A f_Xdx$

so if A is a singleton, you get $\int_a^a f = 0$

What I'm confused about is how this works with the countable additivity requirement on measures. Namely, the inverse image of a singleton set {a} should yield some set in $\Omega$. Let's call this set $S = X^{-1}({a})$. If the measure P(S) = 0, then for some other set in $\mathbb{R}$ called {a, b} should have probability measure $P(X^{-1}(\{a, b\})) = 0 + 0$. In which case you can induct and everything has probability measure 0.

How do you justify this basic fact of continuous RVs in a measure theoretic way?

Comment: All sets with nonzero measure are uncountable, so countable additivity doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In which case you can induct and everything has probability measure 0." - Induction only works for finite values, so you can only show that if A is finite, $P[X^{-1}(A) ] = 0.$

You can get more than that: by using countable additivity you can show any **countable** set has measure zero under X, that is, if A is countable, $P[ X^{-1}(A) ] = 0$.

You get even more, note that the $P[ X^{-1}(A) ]$ will be an integral with respect to the Lebesgue Measure. If A has measure zero (even if it is not countable), we will have

$$
P[ X^{-1}(A) ] = \int_A{f_Xdx} = 0.
$$

This is because the integral of any function on a set of measure zero is zero.

So there is no problem: probabilities will be zero on sets of measure zero, but they can be positive on other larger sets. You can't use countable additivity to show all sets have measure zero since these sets will be uncountable.

Comment: I see, thank you!